# how to print multiple object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

unable to print multiple objects in the console ?
Json Data :-

```
[{"id":101,"email":"xxxx@gmail.com","mn":"+0000000","ut":0,"gen":0,"cy":0,"cp":0},{"id":102,"email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","mn":"+00000","ut":0,"gen":0,"cy":0,"cp":0},{"id":103,"email":"xxxx@gmail.com","mn":"+000000","ut":0,"gen":0,"cy":0,"cp":0}
```

also I have to attach this to above div in a loop using

```
$('div#datainfo').text(mn);
```

i m using this :-

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
};
```

error :-

> [] (null arrary)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and proper details of any errors and a proper explanation of expected results

Comment: Did you check the updated answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var data = [
{
"id":101,
"email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
"mn":"+0000000",
"ut":0,
"gen":0,
"cy":0,
"cp":0
},
{
"id":102,
"email":"xxxxx@gmail.com",
"mn":"+00000",
"ut":0,
"gen":0,
"cy":0,
"cp":0
},
{
"id":103,
"email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
"mn":"+000000",
"ut":0,
"gen":0,
"cy":0,
"cp":0
}
];
 for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
    $('div#datainfo').append('<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">'+
 '<p>Mobile:- <b id="">'+ data[i].mn+'</b></p>'+
 '<p>Name :- <b>'+ data[i].email+'</b> </p>'+
 
 '</div>');
};


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<div id='datainfo'>

</div>
</div>
```

Use `append` to make sure that the previous text inside the `div` persist.

Comment: hey thanks but i want to print all data in bootstrap alert class

Comment: Ok let me do that

Comment: You can use alert-info, or alert-warning or alert-danger class if you want to.

Comment: hey sorry but i have to add all element id , email , name example :- <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                            <p>Mobile:- <b id="">9820132288</b></p>
                            <p>Name :- <b>Mahesh Kadam</b> </p>
                      </div>

Comment: Check the updated answer. I do not see name key in the JSON array so if there is any key related to name then use that instead of email which i have used now.

Comment: hey thanks its working. But what is the best way to do this because u have performed multiple tasks on this code. i already put my number in above comment. if possible contact me on whatsapp

Comment: This is a nice way to achieve. There were several code changes since you asked for it. Otherwise the thing you posted in the question was done in the first hit.

Comment: yes u r correct. but this is the left side of the panel using this i have perform right side operation using id of the left side div